# Ionic 5 responsive ion-img inside ion-card

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I want the ion-card to have a specific size and the ion-card-content to fit the ion-card.

Happens that inside ion-card-content I have an image that doesn't fit the ion-card sizes (height more precisely).

Here is the code:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-row *ngFor="let card of cardData">
    <ion-col>
      <ion-card style="height: 150px;">
        <ion-card-title>{{card.cardTitle}}</ion-card-title>
        <ion-card-content >
          <ion-img [src]="card.cardImageSrc"></ion-img>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-infinite-scroll threshold="100px" (ionInfinite)="loadMoreData($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles" loadingText="Loading more data...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

And this is the result

[image]

I don't want the images to be cropped. I want them to fit the card no matter the size of the card. Already tried a lot of solutions found online but no one seems to work, since ion-card-content is always bigger than the ion-card

Answer (score 1):

Since you have set the `height` attribute on `<ion-card>` to **150px**, then you have to set the `height` attribute on `<ion-img>` to a value less than **150px** (*i.e 100px, Since you also have the title inside the ion-card*).

Your code will be like the following

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-row *ngFor="let card of cardData">
    <ion-col>
      <ion-card style="height: 150px;">
        <ion-card-title>{{card.cardTitle}}</ion-card-title>
        <ion-card-content >
          <ion-img [src]="card.cardImageSrc" style="height: 100px;"></ion-img>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-infinite-scroll threshold="100px" (ionInfinite)="loadMoreData($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles" loadingText="Loading more data...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Perhaps I didn't explain well, but I want the image to fit the card no matter the size of the card. If I set the ion-card to a specific height all inside should adjust